# what will be after "you" body or bodies

Tags: grammar

to be healthy we must keep our bodies clean by having bath as water and soaps wipe away the germs and dirt from our body and keeps us healthy - i want to know that in that line what will be after "our"- "body" or "bodies"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to EL&U.  You might want to visit [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), also in the Stack Exchange group of websites.

If you want to be consistent in your use of the plural *bodies*, I suggest you word the sentence as follows:

> "To be healthy, we must keep our bodies clean by taking baths with soap and water, as they wipe away germs and dirt from our bodies and keep us healthy."

Notice:

- I use the word *keep* because this verb is linked to the plural *baths*; in other words, "baths [they] wipe away germs . . .."
- I use the plural *bodies* the second time simply to be consistent with the use of *bodies* the first time, and because you used the words *we* and *us*, which need the plural, *bodies*.
- I use the singular *soap* because the plural *soaps* is not correct

Here is a different sentence which says the same thing as your sentence:

> "Frequent baths with soap and water help to keep us healthy by washing away dirt and germs from our bodies."

This sentence is shorter, more succinct, and says essentially what you said, but in fewer words.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you sir it has helped me a lot . sir i have one more question, you have used taking instead of having i want to know that is it wrong to use having?

Comment: @SudipDebnath:  There is not much difference between "taking a bath" and "having a bath."  Perhaps "taking a bath" is more American-sounding, but I am not sure.  Feel free to use either expression, whichever you are more comfortable with.  Don